# Python - queuing one function

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, listener, python-multithreading

I've just started learning python, but I have problem with my code:

```
import pifacecad

    # listener initialization
    cad = pifacecad.PiFaceCAD()
    listener = pifacecad.SwitchEventListener(chip=cad)
    listener.register(4, pifacecad.IODIR_ON, blowMyMind)
    listener.activate()

    def blowMyMind(event):
        print('some prints...')
        time.sleep(4)
        print('and the end.')
```

blowMyMind() will be fired as many times as listener it tells to. That is okay.
My goal is to deactivate listener UNTIL blowMyMind ends. Pifacecad suggest Barrier() to achieve that, at least I think that it was here for that reason(correct me if I'm wrong).

Now it's working as many times as I activate listener event, but It's not like pushing function 99 times at once, but queues it and runs one by one.

With Barriers I think it should look like this:

```
# Barrier
global end_barrier
end_barrier = Barrier(1)

# listener initialization
listener = pifacecad.SwitchEventListener(chip=cad)
listener.register(4, pifacecad.IODIR_ON, blowMyMind)
listener.activate()

def blowMyMind(event):
    global end_barrier
    test = end_barrier.wait()
    print(test) # returns 0, which should not in about 5 seconds
    print('some prints...')
    time.sleep(4)
    print('and the end.')
```

The funny part is when I change *parties* in Barrier initialization it is causing BrokenBarrierError at first listener event.

Actually I think that I completely misunderstood Barrier() I think the problem with it is that all listener events are in one thread instead of their own threads.
It's making me even more confused when I'm reading:

> **parties** The number of threads required to pass the barrier.

from here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

My conclusion: when initializing Barrier(X) it would be realeased when there will be X('or less', 'or more'?) number of threads. That sounds VERY stupid :D

I tried to make it that way with no luck:

```
# listener initialization
global busy
busy = 0
cad = pifacecad.PiFaceCAD()
listener = pifacecad.SwitchEventListener(chip=cad)
listener.register(4, pifacecad.IODIR_ON, blowMyMind)
listener.activate()

def blowMyMind(event):
    global busy
    if busy == 0:
        busy = 1
        print('some prints...')
        time.sleep(4)
        print('and the end.')
        busy = 0
    else:
        return None
```